# MapFileOutputFormat for hadoop 0.20.203

Tags: hadoop

I have a hadoop job which I'd like to output to a MapFile, but I have to run on a cluster running hadoop 0.20.203 which doesn't have a MapFileOutputFormat.  Is there some way to convert the output from SequenceFileOutputFormat (which I believe may contain multiple SequenceFiles) to a MapFile in parallel (It's possibly very big)?
What about an ArrayFile (if the keys are all integers and relatively condensed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MapFileOutputFormat](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.20.203.0/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/MapFileOutputFormat.java) is there in 0.20.203. There is no need for a conversion from a SequenceFile to a MapFile.

FYI, conversion of the SequenceFile to MapFile can be done by opening a SequenceFile and using the [MapFile#fix](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.203.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/MapFile.html#fix%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class,%20boolean,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration%29) which will create an index for the SequenceFile. The precursor of this is that the contents of the SequenceFile should be sorted, an MR job can be created for this. MapFileFixer.java in the [zip](http://examples.oreilly.com/0636920010388/ch04.zip) has the sample code.

Comment: Yes, but that extends the old-style org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat
It's not compatible with http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.205.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#setOutputFormatClass(java.lang.Class)

Comment: There was no mention in the OP about the old/new MR API. BTW, what feature of the new MR API are you using which is not there in the old MR API? Unless, there is a specific requirement it shouldn't be much difficult to port to use the old API. Or else [MapFileOutputFormat](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MapFileOutputFormat.java) is in trunk with the new MR API. You can try to build Hadoop with that code.

Comment: I mean Job.setOutputFormatClass takes an argument of type Class<? extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.OutputFormat>
and MapFileOutputFormat.class is of type Class<? extends org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputFormat>
One's mapreduce.OutputFormat and the other is mapred.OutputFormat.  They're incompatible
EDIT: Sorry, I had Mapper and I meant OutputFormat

Comment: Yes, I understand where you are coming from - then use the old MR API (o.a.h.mapred package) with o.a.h.mapred.JobConf class unless you are using some feature from the new API (o.a.h.mapreduce package) which I don't think you are or write a new MapFileOutputFormat as mentioned in my earlier comment. Just remember that mix-n-match won't work :)